# How to count and compare value of colume in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need to create procedure which will find the worst user in one table by counting status with 'P' and 'U' calculate ratio then compare it with other users, take that user id and find it in another table and write all user information that are in two tables. And i call that procedure from java application.

```
Table Rezervacija
id | SifKorisnikPK | Status
1  |   1           | 'P'
2  |   1           | 'U'
3  |   1           | 'U'
4  |   2           | 'U'
5  |   2           | 'P'
6  |   2           | 'P'
7  |   2           | 'P'
8  |   2           | 'P'
9  |   3           | 'U'
10 |   3           | 'U'
11 |   3           | 'P'
12 |   3           | 'P'
13 |   3           | 'P'
14 |   3           | 'P'
```

So the user with id 2 is worst user because of 4 P's, and one U, so his ratio is 3 P. Then it's should go to Korisnik table and return all the info for user with id 2

I try with this but can't get any return values

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getBadPremiumUsers 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BrLr int
    DECLARE @BrDr int

    SELECT @BrLr = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Rezervacija A
    INNER JOIN Rezervacija B
    ON A.SifKorisnikPK = B.SifKorisnikPK
    WHERE A.Status = 'P')

    SELECT @BrDr = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Rezervacija A
    INNER JOIN Rezervacija B
    ON A.SifKorisnikPK = B.SifKorisnikPK
    WHERE A.Status = 'U')

    SELECT * INTO #PremiKoris FROM Korisnik
    INNER JOIN PremiumKorisnik
    ON SifKorisnik = SifKorisnikPK
    ALTER TABLE #PremiKoris 
    DROP COLUMN Password
    SELECT * FROM #PremiKoris 
    WHERE @BrLr > @BrDr

    DROP TABLE #PremiKoris
END
GO
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two different products. Are you really running same code on both?

Comment: You are right. Edited

Comment: SQL is the language, and still a relevant tag. But you could remove either the MySQL or the SQL Server tag...

Comment: Problem solved. At the end I created 2 temp tables in one count P in other count U then join them, and calculate ratio between this values with the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the worse user using:

```
select r.SifKorisnikPK
from Rezervacija r
where status = 'P'
group by SifKorisnikPK
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

You can then use this in a query to get more information:

```
select k.*
from PremiumKorisnik k join
     (select r.SifKorisnikPK
      from Rezervacija r
      where status = 'P'
      group by SifKorisnikPK
      order by count(*) desc
      limit 1
     ) r
     on r.SifKorisnikPK = k.SifKorisnikPK
```

This does in one query what you describe you want to do.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's not what i need.  With this i only look for how much 'P' someone have and don't compare it with 'U'. I need ratio between this two values and return worst. My bad, I didn't ask question with sufficient precision. I will edit it now so if you can look again i would be very grateful.

Comment: Problem solved. At the end I created 2 temp tables in one count P in other count U then join them, and calculate ratio between this values with the same id. Your answer did give me a hint, so thank you.